# Implementing AsyncTask to make an Httprequestion connection

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to implement the AsyncTask for my android Application,
but it seems that my code is out of date.

Maybe someone can tell check what I am doing wrong:

```
 private class Login extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private final String mUsername;
    private final String mPassword;
    private JSONObject jsonObjectResult = null;
    private String msg = "nothing";
    private String USER_ID = " " ;
    private String userid ;
    Login(String username, String password) {
        mUsername = username;
        mPassword = password;
    }


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.
        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("USERNAME",mUsername));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PASSWORD", mPassword));
```

In this line  where I am using the pairs.add, appears the crash in my application.

```
        jsonObjectResult = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, pairs);

        if (jsonObjectResult == null)
        {
            msg = "No Connection ";
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            if (jsonObjectResult.getInt("success") == 1)
            {

                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObjectResult.getJSONArray("posts");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject RETRIEVED_DATA = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    userid = RETRIEVED_DATA.getString("USER_ID") ;
                }
                msg = jsonObjectResult.getString("message");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                msg = jsonObjectResult.getString("message");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return false;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
        if(success)
        {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            mIntent.putExtra("USER_ID",userid);
            startActivity(mIntent);

        }
        else
        {
            Snackbar.make(getCurrentFocus(),msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }

}
```

Just to have a closer look to the error, it says as follows:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
Process: amjad_apps.amjad.linage_expenses, PID: 27704
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:415)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair;
    at amjad_apps.amjad.linage_expenses.LoginActivity$Login.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:789)
    at amjad_apps.amjad.linage_expenses.LoginActivity$Login.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:770)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~IqHbAP1Z7E6cSG4BJiWlUg==/amjad_apps.amjad.linage_expenses-CCrF4FAnP-KPsx3UAJNBmw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~IqHbAP1Z7E6cSG4BJiWlUg==/amjad_apps.amjad.linage_expenses-CCrF4FAnP-KPsx3UAJNBmw==/lib/x86, /data/app/~~IqHbAP1Z7E6cSG4BJiWlUg==/amjad_apps.amjad.linage_expenses-CCrF4FAnP-KPsx3UAJNBmw==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at amjad_apps.amjad.linage_expenses.LoginActivity$Login.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:789) 
    at amjad_apps.amjad.linage_expenses.LoginActivity$Login.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:770) 
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27704 SIG: 9
```

Comment: NameValuePair, BasicNameValuePair classes were deprecated in Android 6.0 (API 23) and removed in Android 9.0 (API 28), so may need to use another library